# Why is the check_box value not posting to the db

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

When I submit the form below the "published" check_box value is not posting.

> params3 = {"utf8"=>"✓",
>   "authenticity_token"=>"i4SbblLJKIwba9yD30sDQCsir28/xdUxQZ90qYTNn0A=",
>   "story"=>{"name"=>"asdsaddsad", "post"=>"asdasdasdasd",
>   "user_id"=>"13", "image_id"=>"1", "published"=>"1"}, "commit"=>"Save
>   Story", "action"=>"create", "controller"=>"stories"}

```
def create
    @story = Story.new(story_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @story.save
        format.html { redirect_to @story, notice: 'Story was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @story }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @story.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

<%= form_for @story do |f| %>
        <%= f.text_field :name, placeholder: "Enter Title" %>
        <%= f.text_area :post, placeholder: "Enter Story" %>
        <br/>
        <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, value: current_user.id %>
        <%= f.hidden_field :image_id, value: @image.id %>
        <%= f.label "Publish this" %>
        <%= f.check_box :published %>
        <%= f.submit "Save Story" %>
    <% end %>
```

Comment: show your form, and what the data type of `published`?

Comment: sorry, forget to wrap it in the curly braces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data that is being passed to the action is `story` as seen in the `params3` hash. Also, the `published` check box is being posted. Check boxes by default will pass a `1` or `0` to denote true / false. Rails will update the value accordingly and accept `1` or `0` for the value of a checkbox:

```
params3 = {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"i4SbblLJKIwba9yD30sDQCsir28/xdUxQZ90qYTNn0A=",  "**story**"=>{"name"=>"asdsaddsad", "post"=>"asdasdasdasd", "user_id"=>"13", "image_id"=>"1", "published"=>"1"}, "commit"=>"Save Story", "action"=>"create", "controller"=>"stories"}
```

Therefore your object creation will need to use those params. Since you are using Rails 4, you will need to use `strong_parameters` which seems that you are. You will need to verify that `published` is an allowed value in your params hash.

```
def story_params
  params.require(:story).permit(...., :published, ...)
end
```